# how to specify a partial domain in blacklist with SpamAssassin

Tags: spamassassin, blacklist

is there a way to specify a partial domain in the spamassassin blacklist?
I get spam from something like abc@something1.something2.xyz but I also get junk from abc@something3.xyz. if I specify *@*.xyz will that take care of both addresses or must I specify *@*.*xyz and *@*.xyz?

much thanks

john

Answer (score 9):

The SpamAssassin whitelist and blacklist options can include *globs*, not regular expressions. The valid metacharacters are `?` and `*` to match 0-1 or 0-many characters respectively. This is the same as a shell glob.

To blacklist mail from foo.com and *.foo.com the following should work:

```
blacklist_from *@foo.com
blacklist_from *.foo.com
```

Don't be tempted to blacklist `*foo.com`, lest you inadvertently block `someone@totally-legit-foo.com`.

Comment: thanks, will *.foo.com block someone@something.something.foo.com? 

thanks again
john

Comment: Yes, `*.foo.com` will block `someone@something.something.foo.com`

Comment: And if you just want to give this a 'score' (not block immediately) ?